# Laravel Changes in vendor

Tags: laravel

I want to ask that if we directly make changes inside vendor in the specific package and we push it to git ignoring vendor folder 
and when other people clone that and run composer install 
does it save the changes I have made in the vendor or it will install the default files?

Comment: The answer is in your question, git will by default ignore any changes made in your vendor folder unless you tell it otherwise which is not a good practice.

Comment: it will install the default files.

Comment: yes after composer install all changes clean !!!

Answer (score 0):

In your vendor folder, you cannot change because isn't versionning.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes made in your vendor folder will be local only. If cloned by another user they will not receive your changes. If you were to composer update or install locally you would be asked if you wish to override the local changes.

If you wish for your changes in the vendor folder to be available to anyone else cloning your repository, you would need to either fork the library you have made changes to and import it, or you could exclude the specific class you have made changes to and override it using your composer.json.